# Is there a way to add lock to a variable for SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an ETL project by using SSIS 2016. There are more than 200 packages and there is a main package to invoke them by using execute task component. Before each package being invoked, there is a SQL task to access SQL server DB and return a check result to decide if the "Execute Task" component should be invoked. the structure like below:

```
   SQL Task
      |
      |
      |
     \|/
Execute package
```

the SQL Task will return 0 or 1 and the value will decide if the package will be executed or not, since there are a lot of task flow in the main package like above and I don't like to declare a lot of variables to store the value returned by each SQL task, I just want to declare one variable to store it but maybe there is a concurrent issue if I just declare one , so can I add a lock to that variable when SQL task return value to it? Or is there a way to ensure the variable will be accessed safely and the task flow run parallel?

Comment: How is your orchestrator package laid out? Do you have ~200 SQL Tasks to Execute Package laid out?